# Free WordPress.com alternative with better tagging

Tags: web-apps, cms, hosted

I made a small website to catalogue games I've used in my ESL classes ([teachingwhimsy.wordpress.com](http://teachingwhimsy.wordpress.com)). I wanted to sort the games with **[custom taxonomies, a.k.a. groups of tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)**, but it turns out those are only available on WordPress.*org*, which requires you pay for hosting. WordPress.com gives you categories and tags; if you want more than those two groups, you're out of luck. (I've resorted to manually listing tags and categories in the sidebar, but it's hard to redesign if I change my mind.) Filtering by multiple tags is not possible.

I hope to be moving on from English teaching and will probably stop adding to the site in about a year, but I still want it to be useful - hence the requirement for a free package that'll stand on its own when I've stopped adding to the page.

Are there any WordPress.com alternatives that let you have groups of tags?

**Essential:**

- custom tag groups (e.g. "esl level tags", "group size tags", "topic tags" …)
- free, or small one-time fee
- ready-made themes, as otherwise I'll waste time faffing around with design

**Optional but would make me happy:**

- filter by multiple tags (e.g. show all posts tagged with "grammar" and "small group")

**I don't need:**

- my own domain
- a lot of space
- an ad-free website

---

I've considered

- Wordpress.com (current site)

  Pros: elegant, idiot-friendly, allows tag editing
  Cons: tagging is troublesome, idiot-friendly
- Wordpress.org

  Pros: very flexible, many excellent plugins to help with tags
  Cons: need to pay for hosting
- Dreamwidth / Blogger

  Pros: tag list instead of tag clouds
  (can sort tags by prefacing with a category, e.g. "cat: grammar" or "p: 2+")
  Cons: really outdated design
- Tumblr

  Pros: plenty of themes, can customise CSS at my leisure, multiple tag search
  Cons: rudimentary tagging, search function is iffy
- Wix (still looking)

  Pros: ???
  Cons: ???

Comment: I’m confused that you list "Wordpress.org" as a solution that you have considered. -- Does this mean a self-hosted solution (i.e., you have to choose and possibly pay a hoster) is fine?

Comment: No, I *really* don't want to pay for hosting. But I spent so long looking through WP.org that it seemed a shame not to mention it.